# Meson reporting 0.44 on Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: 18.10

If I run `meson -v` it reports back as 0.44.

```
cxf@PC:~$ meson -v
0.44.0
cxf@PC:~$ which meson
/usr/local/bin/meson
```

I think I did something when compiling DXVK on 17.04/17.10/18.04 but I can't remember what. I upgraded to 18.10 from 18.04. How can I fix this?

Comment: Uninstall meson with apt and use meson from pip3.

Comment: That doesn't solve anything and it still returns 0.44. Ubuntu 18.10's repo has meson 0.47 so that ain't the problem.

Comment: Give me `dpkg -l '*meson*'` output?

Comment: ``
dpkg -l '*meson*'
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name             Version       Architecture  Description
+++-================-=============-=============-======================================
un  meson            <none>        <none>        (no description available)
``

Comment: It's weird! dpkg claimed that meson is uninstalled. Why would you have meson v0.44.0?

Comment: I forgot to reinstall it after installing the pip version. https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/GdwjXTC9Tp/

It shows 0.47 is installed <s>but still reports it as 0.44 if I do `meson -v`</s> Actually now it's reporting 0.48.2. Maybe I needed to reboot for it to take effect?

Comment: Likely in your prior Ubuntu install you installed meson 0.44  manually to /usr/local/bin. This would take precedence over any packaged version. (/usr/bin) When you used pip3 to install it overwrote that version in /usr/local/bin hence now showing 0.48.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing meson via `pip3 install meson` and rebooting gives me meson 0.48.2. Still no clue why it was reporting 0.44 when the apt version (0.47) was installed.